# Какой способ шифрования лучше использовать для шифрования текста в контексте android, java?

Tags: android, java, шифрование, текст

Какой способ шифрования лучше использовать для шифрования текста в контексте android, java?

Comment: пример дайте, зачем это нужно? Без примера непонятно, что именно шифровать

Comment: Вообще хочу по интенту передавать текст шифровать и интентом возвращать, хочу найти удобный и надежный способ.

Comment: Решил использовать AES.

Answer (score 1):

http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Rot-13#Java

Comment: криптостойкость маленькая